# Getting error You must choose at least one payment method. in M2E integration in Magento

Tags: magento, error-handling, payment, m2e

HI I have just installed the **M2E** on my localhost and i have set-up the account t on ebay as they suggested.I have follow all the steps to list the products on ebay. But i am getting the below error

> You must choose at least one payment method.
>
> i have choose
>
> Payment on collection accepted   and   Payment on collection in
>   payment options

but still i am getting above error.
Please suggest how can i fix this .

Answer (score 0):

This can occurs if M2E payment method is disabled. Check what "M2E Pro Payment" in System->Configuration->Payment Methods has Enabled=Yes. Then clear Magento cache.